# In which markets does the Xiaomi Redmi 10C have NFC?

Tags: xiaomi, nfc, redmi

I just bought a Redmi 10C from an official Xiaomi Store in Malaysia, but I'm from Australia where we don't really have Xiaomi. There's also not really that much info about them in English.

I naïvely expected all new phones just came with NFC these days since all the kids use it to pay for everything at home. But this is a budget phone and the kids in Australia all probably have way more expensive phones.

While trying to figure out whether I had NFC or not I found some [offical specs on Xiaomi's site](https://www.mi.com/my/product/redmi-10c/specs) including

> **NFC**
> Availability varies between markets
> *Functions may vary in some markets

I'll survive without NFC but I'm still curious. I checked Xiaomi's site for several nearby countries and couldn't find any mentioning that NFC is present.

**So does anyone know which countries / which markets do get a Redmi 10C with NFC support?**

Comment: The main question is: are there two different hardware variants sold unter the same name or is this a software issue? I would assume it is the latter and that in some countries NFC can not be used because Xaomi didn't have the license to enable NFC for that model. To my knowledge every country or region has an institution like the FCC in the USA which tests and certifies wireless devices. May be Xiomi has skipped that test in some countries because they had no plans to sell the phone there?

Comment: @Robert I assume it's more than one hardware configuration, differing by which components they include. But I'm totally new to NFC so maybe you're right. Xiaomi definitely sells this model directly here in Malaysia because I bought it from one of their official shops. It is not sold in my home country. If there's a way to test the hardware or even a hardware teardown I'd be interested.

Comment: @Robert Apparently the previous Redmi series offered both a 9C and 9C NFC in some markets. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJq0g4XRC5U&ab_channel=TechLegend Perhaps there will be a 10C NFC but it's not yet released in any markets? In any case that still doesn't answer the software v hardware question but it suggests differing hardware.